# could not find ant-javafx in gradle app

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

While writing my first app using `JavaFX`, I ensured that `JAVA_HOME` is setup properly, and included the `javafx-gradle-plugin` into my app, but got an error of missing `ant-javafx-library` which actually available in my JDK :(

my `build.gradle` and the error msg I got are below:

```
// set up the kotlin-gradle plugin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
       mavenLocal()    //    mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins:javafx-gradle-plugin:8.8.2"
    }
}

// apply the kotlin-gradle plugin
apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'

// add kotlin-stdlib dependencies.
repositories {
    mavenLocal()  // mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //dependencies from a remote repositor
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.12"
    compile "de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins:javafx-gradle-plugin:8.8.2"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        //Define mainClassName as: '[your_namespace].[your_arctifact]Kt'
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'MyAppKt', "Implementation-Title": "Gradle",
                   "Implementation-Version": 1)
    }
    // NEW LINE HERE !!!
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/kotlin'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

kotlin {
    experimental.coroutines 'enable'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget= 1.8  // optional, Minimum jvmTarget of 1.8 needed since Kotlin 1.1
    kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, by downloading the `javafx.plugin` from [here](http://dl.bintray.com/content/shemnon/javafx-gradle/8.1.1/javafx.plugin).

Then created a 'plugin' folder, and copied that file in it.

Last, I installed this plugging into my `gradle.build` as:

```
apply from: "plugins/javafx.plugin"
```

So, my last `gradle.build` is:

```
// set up the kotlin-gradle plugin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
       mavenLocal()    //    mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
      //  classpath files('plugins/javafx.plugin')
    }
}

// apply the kotlin-gradle plugin
apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply from: "plugins/javafx.plugin"  // apply from: "http://dl.bintray.com/content/shemnon/javafx-gradle/8.1.1/javafx.plugin"

// add kotlin-stdlib dependencies.
repositories {
    mavenLocal()  // mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //dependencies from a remote repositor
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.12"
}


jar {
    manifest {
        //Define mainClassName as: '[your_namespace].[your_arctifact]Kt'
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'MainKt', "Implementation-Title": "Gradle",
                   "Implementation-Version": 1)
    }
    // NEW LINE HERE !!!
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}


sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/kotlin'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

kotlin {
    experimental.coroutines 'enable'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget= 1.8  // optional, Minimum jvmTarget of 1.8 needed since Kotlin 1.1
    kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
}
```

and my app structure, is:

[image]

**UPDATE**
**OPTION 2**

Install the new plugin [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins/javafx-gradle-plugin/8.8.2) by:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()   // or mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile "de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins:javafx-gradle-plugin:8.8.2"
    }
}
```

If interested in using `mavenLocal()` then is can be downloaded using the below command:

```
mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins/javafx-gradle-plugin/8.8.2 -Dartifact=de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins:javafx-gradle-plugin:8.8.2
```

To get the `mvn` command line, you get download it from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi), add it to your `path` then call it from anywhere.